# watchOS 2 image scaling bug (Aspect Fit/Fill)

Tags: watchkit, watchos-2

On watchOS 2 beta 4, Xcode 7 beta 4, Group's image do not scale as I expect.

Actual size of image (named MvF86@2.png) is 215x221 and I want it to be fit in 150x150, but it's just repeat from the top left corner...

[image]

[image]

Should I resize original image itself or something wrong in my settings?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is this a bug in Watch OS2? Used to behave as expected on OS1 !!

Comment: I saw some apps their layout broken on watchOS2 due to this Aspect issue.

Comment: I guess you can file a radar with Apple.

Answer (score 1):

I've gotta same problem, but it seemed the problem was fixed in watchOS 2 beta5 released today. Please check it out!

Answer (score 0):

You need to have the images twice the points you setup in storyboard (for 150x150 group background you need 300x300 image in order for it to look sharp).

Nevertheless, your setup seems to work for me. Do you have the image in the correct group in xcassets? I've got it working this way

[image: group setup]
[image: inspector setup]

Comment: Aspect fit / fill was working as I expected, but its won't work on watchOS2.